# Final Cut Pro X and Compressor straight to YouTube

Tags: youtube, final-cut-pro

Is it possible to use Final Cut Pro X (FCPX 10.0.8) and Compressor 4.0.7 to upload a video straight to YouTube?  I can use the preset FCPX YouTube uploader to do it, but I can't adjust the QuickTime settings from within FCPX. I can also set custom QuickTime settings in Compressor and upload to YouTube from Compressor.  However, when I try to use those Compressor settings in FCPX, I only get the option to save to disk, not upload to YouTube.

**Is there a way to use Compressor through FCPX to upload directly to YouTube?**

p.s. The reason I want to do this is because I am teaching a class and want to upload large (2.5hr) videos to YouTube.  I have a very slow Internet connection, and I'd like to get the process started when I go to bed so that (hopefully) the videos will be uploaded by the next morning when I leave for work.  Final Cut Pro X has the ability to upload directly to YouTube (after all the rendering), but there aren't any custom options for the YouTube upload, and the videos it creates are 4.5GB, taking 10+ hours to upload.  Compressor will make the videos smaller, but unless I can figure out how to do all of the processing and uploading in one shot, I'll have to get up in the middle of the night to do the manual switch.  I'd rather avoid that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. NOTE: Compressor cannot process directly to YouTube, it must first render to the HD, then upload to YouTube. The uploading is automatic if you set it up correctly.

Create your movie in Final Cut X and send to Compressor as usual. This creates a default batch named New Project. In the Settings window, drag the settings for the video you need (there are 7 to choose from) from the HTTP Live Streaming folder into the batch, then drag to a Destination you've created your HD. Once the destination has been chosen, *select the New Project batch* and choose the Job Action tab in the Inspector window. One of the "When job completes:" actions in Inspector is Publish to YouTube. You enter authentication credentials and define Title, Description, Tags, Category, etc, right from the inspector.

[image: Inspector Window with YouTube fields]